# Matching a month and year of a date to a row of dates

Tags: excel, date, indexing, excel-formula, match

I want to match a start date by month and year (regardless of the day) to a corresponding date that is a column header and return the column number of said date.

```
  Name    Start Date   1/7/2015   2/9/2016   4/25/2016  
 ------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------- 
  Steve   1/8/2015     100             350         700  
  Amy     2/2/2016     N/A             250         412
```

The code I have tried is:

```
MATCH(1,(MONTH(B2)=MONTH($C$1:$E$1))*(YEAR(B2)=YEAR($C$1:$E$1)),0)
```

The response is "#Value" when it should return "1" for Steve and "2" for Amy.

Comment: Looks like an array formula to me, either try Ctrl+shift+enter, or implement another index in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment; this is an array formula. So either:

- Confirm the formula through holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and only then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Add in an additional `INDEX`, like so:

  ```
  =MATCH(1,INDEX((MONTH(B2)=MONTH($C$1:$E$1))*(YEAR(B2)=YEAR($C$1:$E$1)),),0)
  ```